# Is it safe to call initializers multiple times on the same 'alloc'ed object?

Tags: objective-c

I can construct a `UIImageView` object with `myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];`

Following application activity affecting the display, if I want to change the image on the UIImageView. I can do so by reassigning it with `myImageView.image = someNewImage`. However this doesn't seem to update the frame dimensions. I can modify those manually, but I have observed in practice that calling `[myImageView initWithImage:someNewImage]` does that for me, and has the advantage of being terser.

However I not sure if it is officially a breach of protocol in Objective C to make multiple calls to *init* methods on an object constructed by a single *alloc*. I wouldn't use it unless it was safe (guaranteed not to crash or cause leaks). Is there evidence that it is unsafe?

My research so far...

This article gives general detail about 'alloc' and 'init' on objects

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocAllocInit.html

This is related SO question

[Why are alloc and init called separately in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385410/why-are-alloc-and-init-called-separately-in-objective-c)

This blog article warns *suppliers* of objects that their init methods may be called multiple times as an effect of the initialization process.

http://www.friday.com/bbum/2009/09/06/iniailize-can-be-executed-multiple-times-load-not-so-much/

Comment: bbum's blog entry discusses +(void)initialize (class level initialization) and not -(void)init.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.

`-init` is written assuming that it is only called once. For example,  `-initWithImage` quoted in Apple's documentation you quoted is implemented as

```
- (id)initWithImage:(NSImage *)anImage {
  ...
  if (self) {
      image = [anImage retain];
  }
  return self;
}
```

This assumes that the ivar `image` doesn't point to a retained object. If called twice, it leaks `image`.

Call `-init...` only once per `alloc`, and call `-init...` immediately after `alloc` by combining them as usual:

```
SomeClass* foo=[[SomeClass alloc] init...: ... ];
```

You should never separate them, because `[anAllocedObject init...]` might return something different from `anAllocedObject`.

Answer (score 1):

No, init (or one of it's variants) should only be called once on any object, as Yuji explained. As far as your `UIImageView` issue goes, I believe you can just call `[imageView sizeToFit]` after assigning your new image, and it will automatically resize it for you.