# NSTimer Pause/ resume leak

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, memory-leaks, nstimer

I wanted to be able to Pause/ Resume my NSTimer and found [this below answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6765300/2749):

> ```
> NSDate *pauseStart, *previousFireDate;
>
> -(void) pauseTimer:(NSTimer *)timer { 
>
>     pauseStart = [[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0] retain];
>
>     previousFireDate = [[timer fireDate] retain];
>
>     [timer setFireDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];
> }
>
> -(void) resumeTimer:(NSTimer *)timer {
>
>     float pauseTime = -1*[pauseStart timeIntervalSinceNow];
>
>     [timer setFireDate:[previousFireDate initWithTimeInterval:pauseTime sinceDate:previousFireDate]];
>
>     [pauseStart release];
>
>     [previousFireDate release];
> }
> ```

which works fine. However when testing my App for Leaks, it tells me that I get a leak in here:

```
[timer setFireDate:[previousFireDate initWithTimeInterval:pauseTime sinceDate:previousFireDate]];
```

Can anyone help me? You can see from the code i used that pauseStart and previousFireDate are retained in the pauseTime method and released in the resumeTimer method.

Many thanks

Sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should never call `init` (or any of the other methods in the same family) on an object twice. ([Here's why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4153456/is-it-safe-to-call-initializers-multiple-times-on-the-same-alloced-object)). Change that line to this:

```
[timer setFireDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:pauseTime sinceDate:previousFireDate]];
```

and you'll be fine.

Comment: Im glad you edited your answer - well done sir! Works like a dream